# JQuery Toggle Issue, Requires Two Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, html

I'm Not too Fluent in Javascript but I managed to alter this code and make it toggle between the Play button and the Pause Button for a song... it goes like so:

```
    $(function()
    {
       $("#plbutton").toggle(function()
       { 
            $("#playit").hide();
            $("#pauseit").show();
       },

       function()
       { 

       });
    });

    $(function() 
    {
       $("#pabutton").toggle(function()
       { 
            $("#pauseit").hide();
            $("#playit").show();
       },

       function()
       {

       });
    });
```

This is the HTML:

```
    <span id="playit"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('WeFuckinBall').play()" id="plbutton"><img src="images/playbutton.png" /></a></span>
    <span id="pauseit" ><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('WeFuckinBall').pause()" id="pabutton"><img src="images/pausebutton.png" /></a></span>
```

and this is the css for the pause span:

```
    #pauseit{
        display: none;}
```

Now When I Click the Play Button It switches to the Pause Button, then When I Click the Pause Button it Switches to the Play but after that It requires TWO Clicks in order to work... It'll pause/play the song but the image wont toggle till you click again...

I tried looking around but due to my minimal knowledge of java and jquery I wasn't able to apply the fixes to my code...

Comment: Why dont your two outer functions have a name?

Comment: Why do you have jQuery AND inline script? Move the inline script to the toggle and call e.preventDefault() - you reload the page onclick of the pause button

Comment: What you are trying to do is very simple, I'd advise you take a day out and read up on simple jQuery.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp

Comment: And perhaps first read http://w3fools.com/ and then go to jquery.com instead

Comment: I definitely will.. thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use links, add e.preventDefault();

if not this should work

```
<span id="playit"><img src="images/playbutton.png" /></span>
<span id="pauseit"><img src="images/pausebutton.png" /></span>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#playit").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#$WeFuckinBall").play() 
    $(this).hide();
    $("#pauseit").show();
  });
  $("#pauseit").on("click", function(e) { 
    $("#WeFuckinBall").pause() 
    $(this).hide();
    $("#playit").show();
  });
});
```

You can even leave out the span

Comment: for some reason it's not toggling between the play and pause button no more

Comment: where would i add the e.preventDefault(); btw? to the function?

Comment: nvm I see what you meant with mariogl's example, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You only need the preventDefault if you keep the link

Comment: toggle(); first hides a div and then shows it. So if the div is already hidden then on the first click toggle seems to do nothing. From second click it starts working properly. Actually it always works properly. I am not able to figure out what to do so that toggle shows the div first. If anyone can answer this hats off to him!!

Comment: The toggle you might think of is no longer supported by jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#plbutton").on("click", function(e)
    { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#playit").hide();
        $("#pauseit").show();
    });
    $("#pabutton").on("click", function(e)
    { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#pauseit").hide();
        $("#playit").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, would it have to be within the function?

Comment: OP has his play/pause code inside the markup, I guess because the id is dynamic, that's because I didn't moved it to my code. Of course it's better not to have inline javascript, but then the code would need more changes, and it's not what OP has asked.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest code i can think of is

**HTML:**

```
<span id="playit"><img src="images/playbutton.png" /></span>
<span id="pauseit" ><img src="images/pausebutton.png" /></span>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
var elems = $("#playit,#pauseit")
elems.on("click", function(){ 
    elems.toggle();
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'playit'){
       $('#WeFuckinBall').play();
    }else{
       $('#WeFuckinBall').pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: how would the span be clickable without a anchor?

Comment: same as a div... when you click on it, the event is listened by the event listener function..

Comment: Seems the answers starts looking more an more like my suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You dont need toggle, simply using `.click()` will solve your problem:

```
$(function()
{

$("#plbutton").click(function()
{ 
        $("#playit").hide();
        $("#pauseit").show();
});

$("#pabutton").click(function()
{ 
        $("#pauseit").hide();
        $("#playit").show();
}

});
```

Comment: Why use 2 document.ready handlers?  I've never seen anyone do that before.

Comment: @Archer: I am just solving the problematic area of the code, rather than confusing the user anymore. How to write a good javascript/Jquery code, I leave it to user to learn by experience.

Comment: @Archer: Yup, I accept it, and removed the duplication in the code, thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: I tried this also but It wouldn't toggle at all between the play and pause span...