# toggle() needs a double click sometimes. I have tried using e.prevenDefault(); its not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

toggle(); should hide the div on first click show on second click and hide on third click. But for the first time to show the div I have to click two times.

```
<div id="wholeinfo_<?php echo $result['userid']; ?>" style="display:none;">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.other_chart').live("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var userid1= $(this).attr("id").split('_').pop();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "d3js/index.php",
        data: "userid="+ userid1,
        cache: false,
        //beforesend: function(){$(".podar").show();},
        success: function(html) {
              //$("#loader_"+userid1).hide();
              $("#wholeinfo_"+userid1).empty().append(html).toggle();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What ancient version of jQuery are you using that it still has live() ?

Comment: are you looking for stop()? https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: or something like clearTimeout?

Comment: First click will show it...second click will hide it...third click will show it....Use the right tools for the job

Comment: It shows data in the div with id="wholeinfo_<?php echo $result['userid']; ?>" but sometimes I have click on the link 2 times before it could show the results. It does not happen always.

Comment: what do you want to do with toggle? Your question is not clear

Comment: @charlietfl you're right. But I have to click 2 times on the first click after that it works on single click.

Comment: @csandreas1 I have edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Toggle Issue, Requires Two Clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445502/jquery-toggle-issue-requires-two-clicks)

Comment: can you update your code to at least run and show your problem?